# Mysql-connector Query Won't Update Value

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to keep track of a timer through MySql.

I have two files, one where it increments the selected table for the selected row (don't know the term for this), this is the code incrementing:

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pip
import time
import mysql.connector
from time import sleep

global score
global countdown

en = "1"
score = 0
countdown = 1
print("Hiya!")


class Tkinter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.root = 0
        self.entry = 0
        self.label = 0
        self.button = 0
        self.timerValue = 2
        self.stopButton = 0
        self.start()
        self.spilSlut = 0

    def run(self) -> 0:
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        global countdown

        #Baggrund
        self.root.geometry("+2+0")
        self.root.config(background="Grey")

        #Timervalue selectors
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, bg="white", fg="black", font=("Fixedsys", 28))
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root, bg="white", fg="black", font=("Fixedsys", 28))

        #Start/Stop Knapper
        self.stopTiden = tk.Button(self.root, bg="red", fg="white", text="Stop Spillet", command=self.stopTid)
        self.startTiden = tk.Button(self.root, bg="green", fg="white", text="Start Spillet", command=self.startTid)

        #Timeren
        self.timerDisplay = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="red", text="Spillet er ikke startet")

        self.timerDisplay.grid(row=2, column=50)
        self.startTiden.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.stopTiden.grid(row=0, column=10)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=10)

        self.root.bind("<KeyPress>", self.read)
        self.Update(self)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def read(self, event):
        key = event.keysym
        try:
            if key == "Return":
                self.getA()
                self.visTid()
        except:
            self.fejlTidvalg()

    def startTid(self):
        self.stopButton = 0


    def getA(self):
        try:
            self.timerValue = float(self.entry.get().format("%.2f", 1.23456))
            print(self.timerValue)
            return self.timerValue
        except:
            print(fejl)

    def stopTid(self):
        self.stopButton = 1
        print("Spillet er stoppet nu")

    def visTid(self):
        self.label.config(text="Det her er timerens slutværdi: {}".format(self.timerValue))

    def fejlTidvalg(self):
        self.label.config(text="FEJL -Vælg Venligst Et Tal")

    def opdaterCountdown(self):
        if self.stopButton != 1:
            self.spilSlut = 0
            self.tidTilbage = self.timerValue - countdown
            self.tidTilbage_minutter = int(self.tidTilbage/60)
            self.tidTilbage_sekunder = (self.tidTilbage) - (self.tidTilbage_minutter * 60)
            self.timerDisplay.config(text="{} minutter, {:.2f} sekunder tilbage".format(self.tidTilbage_minutter, self.tidTilbage_sekunder))
            if self.tidTilbage < 0 or self.tidTilbage == 0 and self.timerValue > 0:
                self.spilSlut = 1

        elif self.stopButton == 1:

            self.timerDisplay.config(text="Spillet er sat på pause")

    def opdaterCountdownSpilSlut(self):
            self.timerDisplay.config(text="Spillet er slut")

    class Update(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, tkinter):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.daemon = True
            self.tkinter = tkinter
            self.start()

        def run(self) -> None:
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                self.tkinter.opdaterCountdown()
                if self.tkinter.spilSlut == 1:
                    self.tkinter.opdaterCountdownSpilSlut()
                    time.sleep(1)


app = Tkinter()

stopTiden = 0

# Login til databasen
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    password="",
    database='',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)

forevigt = 0

while (forevigt != 1):
    doorButton = 0
    stopButton = app.stopButton
    timerValue = app.timerValue
    iTwo = timerValue
    doorButton = 0
    i = 0.00
    mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)

    # Servodøren skal åbnes her i denne kode
    while (app.stopButton != 1):
        # Indtast Pinkoden
        f = int(input(
            "Kodeord - bemærk her, at kodeordene er pinkoderne fra min egen database, bare indtast en værdi mellem 1-6"))
        mycursor.execute("SELECT id,adresse,name,pinkode_brugt,score FROM bois WHERE id=%s", (f,))

        # MySQL Commands
        updaterSlutScoren = "UPDATE bois SET pinkode_brugt = pinkode_brugt +1, score = %s WHERE id = %s"
        updaterTidScoreNu = "UPDATE bois SET tidScoreNu = %s WHERE id = %s"
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

        row_count = mycursor.rowcount
        print(myresult)
        print("number of affected rows: {}".format(row_count))

        if(f == 1):
            print("ommer")

        else:
            if (row_count == 1):

                # Servomotordøren åbner(function)
                print(row_count)
                print(app.timerValue)
                while (i != app.timerValue) and (i <= app.timerValue) and (doorButton != 1) and (app.stopButton != 1):
                    print('%.2f' % i)
                    i = i + 0.01
                    timeLeft = app.timerValue - i
                    iTwo = app.timerValue
                    countdown = float('%.2f' % i)
                    score = str("{}".format('%.2f' % i))
                    mycursor.execute(updaterTidScoreNu, (score,en))
                    print("THIS IS X", app.timerValue)
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    mydb.commit()

                # Hvis spillet stoppes, or i ikke når timerens slutværdi, vil scoren gemmes
                if (i != app.timerValue):
                    # Point bliver tilføjet
                    print(score, i, countdown, myresult)
                    print("Dette er dit resultat: {}".format(score))
                    mycursor.execute(updaterSlutScoren, (score, f))



                else:
                    # Point bliver tilføjet
                    print("Ingen point")
                    mycursor.execute(updaterSlutScoren, (score, f))
            if row_count == 0:
                print("fejl!")

            print("Færdig")
            i = 0
            mydb.commit()

    # Mangler servo-logik, samt en timer
```

And then I have the code, where I am trying to read the value being incremented:

```
tk = Tkinter()

mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)

#Mysql Commands, jeg bruger senerehen
læsTidScoreNu = "SELECT tidSCoreNu FROM bois WHERE id = 1"
læsTidMål = "SELECT tidMål FROM bois WHERE id = 1"
opdaterTidMål = "UPDATE bois SET tidMål = %s WHERE id = %s"

while True:
    mycursor.execute(læsTidScoreNu)
    tidScoreNu = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(tidScoreNu)
    print("1")
    mycursor.execute(læsTidMål)
    tidMål = mycursor.fetchall()
```

tidScoreNu will fetch the correct value, but it won't update, when I run the first code in parallel.

At first I thought it was because, for some reason, the mycursor object didn't "update," but even when I run different commands, it still outputs the same feteched value.

Anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `commit` the query. And don't forget to close it too.

Refer to this link:

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-transaction-management-using-commit-rollback/